# Can one believe in Bhagavad Gita and Nyaya school at the same time?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, vedanta, brahma-sutras, nyaya, nyaya-sutra

Can one read the Ithihasas and also believe in Nyaya? Can one read the Brahma sutras and Nyaya sutras and accept them both Are there any conflicting views between the two?

Comment: Yes. Both of them are consistent. But you would need to do a bit of work here. The Nyaya sutras of Brahma sutras need to be translated to Upanishads (13 principle ones, if they don't actually exist) and then interpret Bhagavad Gita according to it

Comment: Cool, do the Brahma sutras have refutations on Nyaya also where can I find the Nyaya Sutras? What about Vaishieka. @Abhas Kumar Sinha

Comment: As far the best I remember, all shatdarshnas have commentaries on Brahm sutras. They don't explicitly *refutation* anywhere.

Comment: @Abhas Kumar Sinha the Bhagavad Gita states god is a compiler of Vedanta, hence it is only Nyaya that needs to be formatted.

Comment: Yes. That's true. But who told you that only Nyaya is an **exclusive** interpretation of Vedas and Upanishads? Infact this came much later if you go via texts.